# Losing disk space in Ubuntu 25GB SSD

Tags: ubuntu

I have a server working on Ubuntu

And I notice during these days a big loss of space

Storage: 25 GB

Available space: 3.1 GB

Here is the output from `ncdu /`

```
    5.8GiB [##########] /var
    4.0GiB [######    ]  swapfile
    2.0GiB [###       ] /usr
  351.2MiB [          ] /lib
  265.7MiB [          ] /root
  228.9MiB [          ] /opt
   72.7MiB [          ] /home
   37.8MiB [          ] /boot
    9.5MiB [          ] /bin
    7.9MiB [          ] /etc
    7.6MiB [          ] /sbin
    4.1MiB [          ] /libx32
    4.0MiB [          ] /tmp
    3.5MiB [          ] /lib32
  412.0KiB [          ] /run
  340.0KiB [          ] /build
   36.0KiB [          ] /path
e  16.0KiB [          ] /lost+found
    8.0KiB [          ] /media
    4.0KiB [          ] /dev
    4.0KiB [          ] /lib64
e   4.0KiB [          ] /srv
e   4.0KiB [          ] /mnt
    4.0KiB [          ]  cookies.txt
.   0.0  B [          ] /proc
    0.0  B [          ] /sys
@   0.0  B [          ]  initrd.img.old
@   0.0  B [          ]  initrd.img
@   0.0  B [          ]  vmlinuz.old
@   0.0  B [          ]  vmlinuz
```

Do I need to contact server support?

output from  `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            485M  4.0K  485M   1% /dev
tmpfs           100M  408K   99M   1% /run
/dev/vda1        25G   22G  2.1G  92% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            497M     0  497M   0% /run/shm
none            100M  4.0K  100M   1% /run/user
```

output from    `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/vda: 26.8 GB, 26843545600 bytes
214 heads, 23 sectors/track, 10651 cylinders, total 52428800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000233ee

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/vda1   *        2048    52424221    26211087   83  Linux
```

Comment: Output of `df -h` and `fdisk -l` please

Comment: @roaima Updated

Comment: and how about `lsof 2> /dev/null | grep '(deleted)$'`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti https://codeshare.io/GkelyO

Comment: Those five `/run/lock/apache2/*` files are ~2GB each. But something doesn't tally - they're allegedly on `/run/lock` but can't be. If they were symlinked back to somewhere in `/` then that 10GB could account for the missing space

Comment: @roaima What just happened! 0_0 For some reason now the available space is 12GB Thank you, you saved me

Comment: You restarted `apache2`, I'd guess

Comment: True, I reinstalled apache2 and PHP a few days ago And I started losing space, but now after I applied what DopeGhoti told me, I got back more than it was. i can't thank you both enough.

Comment: Did you run `ncdu` as root?  Also it could be files that have been deleted but a program still has open.  These will be freed when you reboot the server or kill all programs that have the files open.

Comment: @psusi yes as root, I haven't restarted the server for a year, but now I've restarted it and it doesn't change much, and after the available space became 12GB for some reason, now start to lose space again and became 7GB

Comment: The other thing to look for is files that are hidden by another mount.  For instance, if you have files in /proc or /dev, once /proc or /dev is mounted over that directory, those files are hidden, but still take up space on the disk.  You might bind mount the root to another directory, then poke around in there checking the directories where you normally mount another filesystem to make sure that they are empty.